# Github page using hexo, how to get my theme supported?

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

I want to host a simple blog on Github pages. Therefore I set up a [repository](https://github.com/lony/lony.github.io) and used Hexo as a compile and deployment tool.

After testing my site locally I run the following command: 
`hexo deploy --generate`

Sadly I, just a few seconds later, get the following message from Github:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> The hacker theme is not currently supported on GitHub Pages. For more
>   information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site.
>
> For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
>
> If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this
>   email.

How can I publish my site using the `hacker` theme? If this is not possible which themes are supported by Github? How do I use them with Hexo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [..] I used the username.github.io repo and deployed directly to master
>   and it works!

https://github.com/CodeDaraW/Hacker/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

**Bypassing Jekyll on GitHub Pages**

> It is now possible to completely bypass Jekyll processing on GitHub
>   Pages by creating a file named .nojekyll in the root of your pages
>   repo and pushing it to GitHub. This should only be necessary if your
>   site uses files or directories that start with underscores since
>   Jekyll considers these to be special resources and does not copy them
>   to the final site.

Source: https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages